# How to generate word document using existing template using POI, Spring MVC, jquery?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I tried some code but it's downloading blank document. If I try to write HWPFDocument object on the response.getOutputStream() then word document is getting corrupted. Need help.

Jquery function

```
$.ajax({ type : "GET",
        url : urlIpd,
        success : function(data) {
        $("#dl-frames").attr("src", urlIpd);
    },

});
```

Controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{partLocnId}/{partnerId}/ipdDwnld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void ipdDwnld(@PathVariable("partLocnId") String partLocnId, @PathVariable("partnerId") String partnerId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HWPFDocument doc = null;
        try {

            response.setContentType("application/msword");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + partnerId +".doc" + "\";");

            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream((new File("C:/templates/IPDV14Q117.ImplementationName.doc"))));
            doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
            doc.getRange();

            Range range = doc.getRange();
            range.replaceText("Integration Process Design", "TEST");

            //ServletOutputStream fos = (response.getOutputStream()); //using this document will get corrupt.
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(partnerId+".doc")); // generates blank document
            doc.write(fos);

            fos.close();                
            doc.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I got it resolved by changing the version of the poi-scratchpad. Earlier it was 3.16 I have modified the dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 3.0.1 is absolutely ancient! You really shouldn't be using such an old version, you should use the latest version if possible